# CSS gradient background no scaling, ends with one color

Tags: css, gradient

I'm trying to make a fixed-height CSS gradient background fade to one color but not repeat the gradient.

[Here's a codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwJGRJ)

```
html {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: yellow;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
    background: linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I want the gradient to end at a specified height and then have the background repeat one color. In the codepen, you can see the gradient ends, but then it's a white background; I want the background to be yellow. I want to do this completely in CSS (without using an image). Thanks.

Comment: You can drop the prefix nowdays. You can also add a `background-color` and eventually use `background-size` instead setting an `height`.  with `height`: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VWRrrX  with `background-size` and no `height`  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/owVoGp works for the html tag ...

Comment: @GCyrillus will that added bg color work in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, read the spec when you have a doubt and try the piece of code from the pen if you have any old browsers to see the fallback working. Before linear-gradient, one used to set a gradient image + bgcolor (1px X 50px repeat horizontaly ;) )  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the height of your page (i.e. `html`) to `50px`, so that all you get. To limit the size of the background, use the `background-size` CSS property. Here is an example:

```css
html {
  background: yellow;
}

body {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
  background: linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50px;
}
```

However, it is always recommended to use a `div` container inside the body rather than using `html`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you set the styling for your HTML tag to 50px. What you want is a wrapper inside your body like `<div id="wrapper"></div>` which you then can style and set to `100vh` height.

Like this:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* your background styles */
}
```